# Инициализация бинов Spring после авторизации

Tags: java, spring

Работаю со Spring в Swing приложении, приложение делится на две главных части:
1. Авторизация
2. Приложение

Авторизация и приложение загружаются в одном Spring контексте, но проблема в том, что загрузка бинов приложения должна инициализироваться после авторизации, так как в авторизации происходит получение id пользователя.
Как правильно сделать чтоб сначала загрузилась авторизация, пользователь авторизовался, а потом подгрузилось основное приложение в этом же контексте.
Или использовать разные контексты?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать инициализацию некоторых бинов ленивой, пометив их аннотацией `@Lazy` в коде или параметром `lazy-init="true"` в конфигурации. Тогда инициализация будет отложена до первого обращения к бину.

Comment: дело в том, что у меня используется для внедрения Autowired, а после этого объект оборачивается в Proxy и не приводится к нужному мне классу. И так как классов приложения подавляющее большинство, думаю неправильно делать их Lazy. Может быть имеет смысл убрать Spring из авторизации и только после авторизации уже загружать контекст и инициализировать бины?

Comment: Это уж вам виднее. Но да, ни что не мешает инициализировать контекст позже.

Comment: Спасибо, рассмотрю такой вариант подробнее.